# What does 'iconic' mean

Tags: vocabulary

I rember my friend looks at the picture of her and boyfriend kissing in time square in New York, she stares  at the picture and said 'this is the most iconic thing that ever happen  in time square'.  I though iconic refers to a symbol . Can anybody  explain it  to me, as wide as possible.

Comment: I would say that the 'icon' is not what happened - it is the photograph that is an icon.

Comment: So is that mean if something  is iconic, it is impressive  and important and likely to have an influence  on others in a particular  way

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-J_Day_in_Times_Square

> V-J Day in Times Square (also V-Day and The Kiss) is a
>   photograph by Alfred Eisenstaedt that portrays a U.S. Navy sailor
>   grabbing and kissing a stranger—a woman in a white dress—on Victory
>   over Japan Day ("V-J Day") in New York City's Times Square on August
>   14, 1945. The photograph was published a week later in Life
>   magazine, among many photographs of celebrations around the United
>   States that were presented in a twelve-page section titled "Victory
>   Celebrations".

[image]